# Parametrizing base image version in Dockerfile of Docker container Github action

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am following ["Creating a Docker container action"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action) and everything works great for me except that I would like to parametrize `FROM` field in my `Dockerfile` (I need to run CI tests against different versions of dependency, packaged as Docker image).

Ideally, in my `Dockerfile`, I'd like to use [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) or something something similar to:

```
ARG version=latest


FROM alpine:${version}

...
```

... but it is unclear how to pass build args.

Is there a way to something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a good way to do this out of the box.

At the moment Docker container action
won't even let you to specify Dockerfile using arguments (through `runs.image` in `action.yml`).

The solution for me was using [this action](https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action).